# "'n'" as an abbreviation for "and" as in "rock 'n' roll"

Tags: orthography, conjunctions, abbreviations, apostrophe

I wonder if there are other cases where *and* is abbreviated in writing as in *rock 'n' roll*.

Comment: How about "Fish 'n' chips"

Comment: Brand names use it. I've seen Cash'n'Carry, Pak'n'Save [sic], but marketing people will do weird things to language, so these may not count.

Comment: "Guns N' Roses"

Comment: *Smash 'n' grab* and *drum 'n' bass* come to mind

Comment: @Al, @Matt : thanks. I had such musical examples just in front on my nose and did not see them.

Answer (score 11):

The word "and" is frequently reduced to just *'n'* in speech. For that reason, brand names, abbreviations, catchphrases, and other forms of informal, snappy language will often use the spelling *'n'*. Examples that I've seen include:

- rock 'n' roll
- fish 'n' chips
- pork 'n' beans
- mac 'n' cheese
- Park 'n' Ride
- Cash 'n' Carry
- mom 'n' pop

Of course, most of these also exist with the full word *and* written out. In principle, any reasonably common phrase could be spelled this way if you wanted to, though it would be improper to do so in formal writing unless you're reproducing a brand name.

Comment: Or the famous Victoria Wood "Dinnerladies" script explaining the difference between tuna 'n' sweetcorn and tuna and sweetcorn

Comment: please add "Guns N' Roses"