# Should a contraction taken from the center of a word have two apostrophes?

Tags: orthography, contractions

I'm currently reading *Entrepreneur Magazine,* and there is a story profiling a 13-year-old who created a series of stickers to embellish Lego blocks. The subtitle of the story reads

> A pint-size 'trep solves a sticky toy dilemma

This doesn't seem right to me. Since *'trep* is a contraction of entrepreneur, and the word is losing *en-* from the left side and *-reneur* from the right. Wouldn't the correct subtitle read

> A pint-size 'trep' solves a sticky toy dilemma

Yes, it looks awful, but wouldn't it be technically correct?

Comment: Related: [“'n'” as an abbreviation for “and” as in “rock 'n' roll”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26752/n-as-an-abbreviation-for-and-as-in-rock-n-roll)

Comment: It's related, but it's certainly not the same question. That question is asking for examples of double apostrophe usage for a specific word. This is a grammatical, orthographic question related to any word you could want to contract from both ends.

Comment: Can we at least agree that "trep" is a horrifying and wholly unnecessary contraction and that the author of this article should have their fingers 'oppe' off?

Comment: I 'econ' 'at 'otion.

Comment: @Dancrumb I'd never use it, it *is* horrifying and wholly unnecessary - but as a matter of professional solidarity I would never deny an author the right to pander to his audience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Trep* may not be a contraction at all but a [*clipping*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipping_%28morphology%29).

> In linguistics, **clipping** is the word formation process which consists in the reduction of a word to one of its parts (Marchand: 1969). Clipping is also known as "truncation" or "shortening."

*Trep* would be an example of **Middle clipping**: similar to flu (*influenza*), jams (*pajamas*) etc. and as such probably doesn't require any apostrophes.

There is also **back clipping**:  ad (advertisement), cable (cablegram), doc (doctor), exam (examination), fax (facsimile), gas (gasoline), gym (gymnastics, gymnasium), memo (memorandum), mutt (muttonhead), pub (public house), pop (popular music).

And **fore-clipping**: chute (parachute), coon (raccoon), gator (alligator), phone (telephone), pike (turnpike), varsity (university)

Comment: 'Fore-clipping' irresistibly suggests circumcision.

Comment: @StoneyB- I hope you don't live [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regina,_Saskatchewan)

Comment: That's a fair thought . . .